# Cygwin: how do I disable /cygdrive

Tags: security, access-control-list, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I'm using a cygwin based SSHD server and I want to disable the /cygdrive/c and /cygdrive/d paths; is this possible?  Using NTFS ACLs to achieve this will be a mess because the user will need access to the drive with the SSH daemon on it so I can't just block access at the drive level, but would need to adjust a lot of folder separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure ACLs are the only way to do this